# Cross referencing, forward declarations, etc: In which order?

Tags: c++, function, class, forward-declaration

Let :

```
class A
{
    typedef A (* func_t)( A a );

    func_t * _func;
};
```

In what order do I have to write this, and what forward declaration do i need (if any), so that it compiles ?

This is my real code, if needed :

```
class Value
{
public:

   typedef Value (* func_t)( const std::vector< Value > & args );

private:

   union
   {
      /// ...

      func_t * _f;
   }
   _data;

   // ...
};

Value Value::operator () ( const std::vector< Value > & args ) const
{
   if( this->isFunction() )
   {
      return this->_data._f( args ); // ERROR
   }
   else
   {
      throw exception( "Value::operator () - Not an E_FUNCTION." );
   }
}
```

Which gives me the error :

```
error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments
```

Thanks for your help :)

EDIT : I also tried  to declare the function pointer type before, after, and inside the class, but there is always a problem.

Comment: You declare `func_t` to be a pointer to a (non-member) function, and then you declare the member variable `_func` to be a pointer to `func_t`. In other words `_func` is a pointer to a pointer to a non-member function. I doubt that's what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order looks ok. What does not look ok is

```
func_t * _f;
```

You are declaring a pointer to a pointer to member and then you try to use it as pointer to member. Use normal pointer to member instead:

```
func_t _f;
```